# Flutter App stuck at Installing build/app/outputs/flutter-apk/app-debug.apk... or xcode build done on iOS

Tags: android, ios, flutter, xcode

I got an M2 Macbook where I wanted to run my Flutter App which was previously built on an Intel chip. The App does not show any error but can't be installed on both Android and iOS after the build finishes. I updated all dependencies but no solutions.

Android output:

````
Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'...
Invalid depfile: /Users/taoufik/StudioProjects/culture_islamique_mac/.dart_tool/flutter_build/3411ceaa9368a0738c9da3ffddc7daff/kernel_snapshot.d
Invalid depfile: /Users/taoufik/StudioProjects/culture_islamique_mac/.dart_tool/flutter_build/3411ceaa9368a0738c9da3ffddc7daff/kernel_snapshot.d
✓  Built build/app/outputs/flutter-apk/app-debug.apk.
Installing build/app/outputs/flutter-apk/app-debug.apk...```

**iOS Output**

```Launching lib/main.dart on iPhone 15 in debug mode...
Running Xcode build...
Xcode build done.                                           28.9s
[ERROR:flutter/shell/platform/darwin/graphics/FlutterDarwinContextMetalImpeller.mm(42)] Using the Impeller rendering backend.
Error connecting to the service protocol: failed to connect to http://127.0.0.1:61374/pQCKnqnVpG8=/
the Dart compiler exited unexpectedly.```


Then runner quit.
````

Comment: Have you ran flutter doctor -v

Comment: Yes I did, No issue found.

Comment: The transition from Intel to M1/M2 architecture can cause compatibility issues with build caches.

Try to clear your cache .. I can update what you need to do

Answer (score 1):

The issue can be related to architecture compatibility between the Intel-based and M1/M2-based Macs caches.

Try these steps

For Android:

- flutter clean
- flutter pub get
- open android folder from android studio if you have(optional)
- click build/clean from android studio
- build/rebuild
- flutter run

For ios

- Open the iOS module of your project in Xcode (open ios/Runner.xcworkspace)
- Go to Project > Build Settings, search for Excluded Architectures, and remove any entries under this setting to ensure compatibility with the ARM architecture of M1/M2 chips.
- Clean the build folder in Xcode (Product > Clean Build Folder)
- flutter clean
- flutter pub get
- flutter run

Comment: Thank you my friend, I really appreciate. Google frameworks especially firebase are the one causing the App to crush, so I disable them. It run successfully after that. Now I will work on them to see what is the real issue.

I am using: Analytics, Mobile_ads, App_messaging and google fonts. Any advice on how to approach them will be welcome. Thanks again

Comment: are you able to get a log of the crash because the above log says nothing about them.

then you can check it the solution already exist here. else share the link with me